# Series convergence: $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}{n^{2/3}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can I test convergence for this series ? Comparison, limit test fail for me.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\sin{\frac{n\pi}{2}}}{n^{2/3}}$$

Comment: Consider the first $7$ terms and try to spot the pattern

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT:

You can simplify to

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{i}}{(2n+1)^{2/3}}$$

Now, do you know the [Alternating Series Test](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcII/AlternatingSeries.aspx)?

Comment: yes.It seems nice solution. Is there another way to try also ?

Comment: @Parhs: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test

Comment: great! I'll use that too...

Answer (score 2):

Separate the cases  $n=2p$ and $n=2p+1$ we write the given series on the form

$$\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{\sin((2p+1)\pi/2)}{(2p+1)^{2/3}}=\sum_{p=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^p}{(2p+1)^{2/3}}$$
and then use the Leibniz criteria.